# how to convert entity collection to a array

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity

I want to select some database int values to integer array.Below code is getting error

```
 int[] lst = contxt.tbl_ReportingAthorityDetails.Where(x => x.isDelete == false && x.reportingAthority == lgdempid).Select(x => new { x.employeeId}).ToArray();
```

error is

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'int[]'
```

Comment: The important question is why?

Answer (score 2):

Using anonymous type in Select causes this error.

Rewrite your "Select" part of query to:

```
.Select(x => x.employeeId).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select(x => x.employeeId).ToArray()
```

Should be enough instead of

```
Select(x => new { x.employeeId}).ToArray()
```

The latter produces instances of an anonymous class whose only member is of type int and that cannot be cast to anything but object.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this as presently it will create an instance of anonymous class:

```
.Select(x => x.employeeId).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the "new" in your select query which create the anonymous type class.

> Select(x => **new { x.employeeId}**).ToArray()

removing that new will solve the issue.

> contxt.tbl_ReportingAthorityDetails.Where(x => x.isDelete == false &&
>   x.reportingAthority == lgdempid).**Select(x => x.employeeId)**.ToArray();